# Cargar Multiples imágenes laravel 7

Tags: laravel, imagen, relaciones, carga

Tengo un proyecto que en el formulario carga una imagen y varios campos más. Estoy necesitando cambiar el modo de carga de una sola imagen a múltiples imágenes.

Hice los siguientes cambios y no me termina de funcionar.

En la vista agregue 'enctype' => 'multipart' y al input 'imagenes[]' con esto me permitió agregar múltiples imágenes.

**VIEW**

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'properties.store', 'files' => true, 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data' ]) !!}
            
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ Form::label('detallePropiedad', 'Detalle de la propiedad') }}
                {{ Form::textarea('detalle_propiedad', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'rows' => '2']) }}
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                {{ Form::label('descripcionPropiedad', 'Descripción de la propiedad') }}
                {{ Form::textarea('descripcion_propiedad', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'descripcion_propiedad']) }}
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                {{ Form::label('cantidad_ambientes', 'Cantidad de ambientes') }}
                {{ Form::text('cantidad_ambientes', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'cantidad_ambientes']) }}
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                {{ Form::label('direccion_propiedad', 'Dirección de la propiedad') }}
                {{ Form::text('direccion_propiedad', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'direccion_propiedad']) }}
            </div>



            {{-- Carga las imagenes --}}
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ Form::label('imagenes', 'Imágenes de la propiedad') }}

                {!! Form::file('imagenes[]', ['multiple' => 'multiple'],  ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'imagenes']) !!}
            </div>

            @if (count($errors) > 0)
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <strong>Whoops!</strong> Hay un problema con las imágenes, inténtelo de nuevo por favor.<br><br>
                    <ul>
                      @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                          <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                      @endforeach
                    </ul>
                </div>
            @endif

            <div class="form-group">
                {{ Form::submit('Guardar', ['class' => 'btn btn-sm btn-primary']) }}
            </div>
            
        {!! Form::close() !!}
```

**CONTROLLER**
En el controlador cambié la forma de carga por un foreach que recorre el array imagenes[] lo genera bien, pero me dice que no tengo un el image_id y entiendo que no por que aun no guarde la imagen.

```
public function store(PropertyStoreRequest $request)
{
  if($request->hasFile('imagenes'))
    {

        $allowedfileExtension=['jpg','png'];

        $files = $request->file('imagenes');

        foreach($files as $file){

            $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();

            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

            $check = in_array($extension,$allowedfileExtension);

            // dd($check);

            if($check)
            {

                // $items= Item::create($request->all());
                $properties = Property::create($request->all());

                foreach ($request->imagenes as $photo) {

                $filename = $photo->store('imagenes');
                
                Image::create([

                'filename' => $filename

                ]);

                }

            }else{

                echo '<div class="alert alert-warning"><strong>Warning!</strong> Sorry Only Upload png , jpg , doc</div>';

            }

        }

    }   
}
```

En la tabla propiedades cree una foreign

```
$table->foreignId('image_id')->references('id')->on('images')
            ->onDelete('cascade')
            ->onUpdate('cascade')
            ->nullable();

public function image(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Image::class);
}

Y en la imagen
    class Image extends Model
    {
     protected $table = 'images';
      protected $fillable = [
        'filename'
       ];

      public function properties(){
        return $this->hasMany(Property::class);
      }
   }
```

Lo que necesito es poder guardar muchas imágenes de una propiedad.
Me podrían iluminar el camino de los pasos que debo seguir, como sería la lógica apropiada para hacer esto correctamente. Valoro toda sugerencia.

Comment: Si necesitas que una propiedad tenga muchas imágenes, la relación es al revés. Cada imagen debería tener una columna propiedad_id y una relación `propiedad()`, que sea belongsTo(Propiedad).

Comment: Si me di cuenta después que lo estaba haciendo mal. Muchas gracias @porloscerrosΨ